# C# Selenium Edge - get running instance of Edge browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I'm looking for a code where we can use the running instance of the browser of MS edge which open manually by the user. I know we can use that on Chrome driver but not able to use it on Edge browser. Thanks

Comment: is it chromium based?

Answer (score 2):

Type : **edge://version/** in browser you will get executable path of msedge.exe

copy this and close all edge instance.

**now  start edge as:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --remote-debugging-port=5555
```

**Now add remote debugging port as:**

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.UseChromium = true;
options.AddAdditionalCapability("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:5555");
var driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```